# Fourier expansion of logarithmic derivative of $j$ function

Tags: special-functions, series-expansion

I am interested in examining the Fourier coefficients of functions of a couple of weight $2$ modular forms which are essentially logarithmic derivatives of Klein's modular function
$$j(\tau) = q^{-1} + 744 + 196884q + 21493760q^2 + \cdots, \qquad q := e^{2\pi i\tau}.$$
The two functions I want to see the $q$ expansions of are 
$$f(\tau) = \frac{j'(\tau)}{j(\tau)}$$
and
$$g(\tau) = \frac{j'(\tau)}{j(\tau) - 1728}.$$
Does anyone know how to do this in *Mathematica* 11? I know there is the built in function `KleinInvariantJ` but that seems to be useful for evaluating the function, not giving the $q$ expansion. Thanks.

Comment: Are those primes derivatives with respect to $q$, or to $\tau$?

Comment: `Series[1728*KleinInvariantJ[τ], {τ, 0, 4}]` seems to give your first series.  Then isn't it a matter of applying `Series` on the combinations?

Comment: @QuantumDot - I believe that the definition of `q` needs to be changed to `q  == Exp[-2 Pi I / τ]`

Comment: @Bob, there are two different conventions for the nome $q$ in place; sometimes one uses $q$ to denote $\exp(\pi i\tau)$ (personally, the convention I'm accustomed to) and sometimes one uses it for what is otherwise denoted as $\bar{q}=\exp(2\pi i\tau)$, which is apparently the convention the OP is using. Have a look at the [MathWorld article](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/j-Function.html) for the Klein invariant, for instance.

Comment: @J.M. - The series expansion `Series[1728*KleinInvariantJ[τ], {τ, 0, 4}]` has the `τ` in the denominator of the exponent of `E`

Comment: @Bob, OTOH, it's definitely a property of the Klein *invariant* to take the same value even under a modular transformation, so I guess that's fine: `With[{τ = N[-4 + 3 I, 20]}, 1728 {KleinInvariantJ[τ], KleinInvariantJ[τ + 1], KleinInvariantJ[-1/τ]}]`, I'm not sure why *Mathematica* is being ornery and insists on expressing the series in terms of $-1/\tau$ instead of $\tau$, tho.

Comment: @QuantumDot How exactly do I form the combinations? And how do I take the derivative of $J$? Thanks.

Comment: You still haven't answered my question; which variables are those primes differentiating with respect to? The results are different for both $\tau$ and $q$.

Comment: My mstake. I meant differentiation with respect to $\tau$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The relationship between `KleinInvariantJ[τ]` and the Alwaise's (OP) definition is:

```
alwaiseJ[q_] = 1728*KleinInvariantJ[-((2 I π)/Log[q])]
```

To check this, apply `Series` to recover the OP's expansion (apparently, there is a *bug* causing not enough terms to be displayed):

```
Series[alwaiseJ[q], {q, 0, 4}] // Expand

(* 744 + 1/q + 196884 q + 21493760 q^2 *)
```

To obtain series expansions for the combinations requested by the OP, the ideal method is simply to form the combination and apply `Series`.  But after a minute of computing time it yields an overly complicated (propbably wrong) result:

```
Series[D[alwaiseJ[q], q]/alwaiseJ[q], {q, 0, 3}]

(*Probably wrong result?*)
```

A workaround is to apply `Series` on each `alwaiseJ`, apply the necessary derivative, and then apply `Series` on the final result:

```
Series[D[Series[alwaiseJ[q], {q, 0, 10}], q] / Series[alwaiseJ[q], {q, 0, 10}], {q, 0, 3}]

(* -(1/q) + 744 - 159768 q + 36866976 q^2 - 8507424792 q^3 + O[q]^4 *)
```

Same thing for OP's second example:

```
Series[D[Series[alwaiseJ[q], {q, 0, 10}], q] / (Series[alwaiseJ[q], {q, 0, 10}] - 1728), {q, 0, 3}]

(* -(1/q) - 984 - 574488 q - 307081056 q^2 - 164453203992 q^3 + O[q]^4 *)
```

Comment: Thanks! Just one question. How do I get mathematica to actually multiply the coefficients of $J$ by $1728$? When I type in the code you have here and apply Series to alwaiseJ, Mathematica displays
$$1728\left(\frac{31}{72} + \frac{1}{1728q} + \frac{1823q}{16} + \frac{335840q^2}{27}\right).$$
How can I make it actually distribute the $1728$? Thanks.

Comment: @EthanAlwaise `Expand` should do the trick.

Answer (score 2):

Some trickery is necessary here. In particular, we will need to use the expression of the [$j$-invariant in terms of theta functions](http://dlmf.nist.gov/23.15.E7):

```
jf = With[{a = EllipticTheta[2, 0, Sqrt[#]]^8, b = EllipticTheta[3, 0, Sqrt[#]]^8, 
           c = EllipticTheta[4, 0, Sqrt[#]]^8}, 32 (a + b + c)^3/(a b c)] &;
```

and expand as a series in the nome:

```
ser = Series[jf[q], {q, 0, 6}]
   1/q + 744 + 196884 q + 21493760 q^2 + 864299970 q^3 + 20245856256 q^4 +
   333202640600 q^5 + 4252023300096 q^6 + O[q]^(49/8)
```

before using the chain rule judiciously.

$f(\tau)$:

```
2 π I q D[Log[ser], q]
   -2 I π + 1488 I π q - 319536 I π q^2 + 73733952 I π q^3 - 17014849584 I π q^4 +
   3926422987488 I π q^5 - 906079372542144 I π q^6 + 209091033317387904 I π q^7 + O[q]^50
```

$g(\tau)$:

```
2 π I q D[ser, q]/(ser - 1728)
  -2 I π - 1968 I π q - 1148976 I π q^2 - 614162112 I π q^3 - 328906407984 I π q^4 - 
  176125996903968 I π q^5 - 94314016488431808 I π q^6 - 50504368485468650880 I π q^7 - 
  27044667899456355041328 I π q^8 - 14482193986413608035836912 I π q^9 - 
  7755094033419666997380722976 I π q^10 - 4152788142706024277284841200704 I π q^11 - 
  2223783397581264170979224652742848 I π q^12 -
  1190817453099277203894595701810883488 I π q^13 + O[q]^(105/8)
```